# how to convert a dataframe into time series

Tags: python, time-series

```
def dataset():
   with sqlite3.connect("project.db") as db:
            cursor1=db.cursor()
             d1= "select date1,delta from Payment"
             cursor1.execute(d1)
            df=DataFram(data=cursor1.fetchall(),columns=['date','delta'])
            print df.head()
            print '\n Data Types'
            print df.dtypes
            print df.index
            df.info()
```

How can i make this dataframe a time series?
Thank you all.

[image]

Comment: A time series implies that the index is a `DatetimeIndex` so what is the current index? What does `df.info()` show?

Comment: i have edited the question :-)

Comment: You need to do `df.index = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])` to set your index to `datetimeindex`

Comment: thanks, it worked. :-) @EdChum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A time-series implies that the index needs to be `DatetimeIndex`, judging from your link to your image you need to set your index after conversion:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

Comment: after running what you suggest, then `type(df)` it still prints pandas.core.frame.DataFrame. I believe what we're looking for is a timeseries object, right? According to McKinney, Wes. Python for Data Analysis: Data Wrangling with Pandas, NumPy, and IPython (Kindle Location 6861). O'Reilly Media. Kindle Edition. ...when we run `df.index`, it should print: 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'

Comment: @RyanChase I don't have the latest version on my laptop, firstly the type of `df` should remain as a `pandas.DataFrame` the index on my machine changes to `pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex` as I don't have access to your data and code I can't comment further as to why it doesn't work for you

Answer (score 1):

Could you please show a concrete example of your data?

Your dataframe can be a time series as long as the index is dates in a `pandas.datetime` format.
To achieve that, you can type:

```
df.index = pandas.datetime.strptime("date_field")
```